# regex to check if a link is valid on an image

Tags: jquery

I have an input field for input a URL to an image.

Now I want to take care, that the image is correct (syntax) and the image matched to an image file.

I tried it with this

```
function check_link(url){
   url_validate= /(http(s?):)([/|.|\w|\s|-])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)/;
   if(!url_validate.test(url)){ return false; }else{  return true; }
}
```

In some cases it failed

- http://www.bla/ig.png - will be not ok but it return true
- http://bla/ig.png - will be also not ok but it also return true
- http://www.bla.jpg - will be also not ok but it also return true
- http:www.bla.jpg  - will be also not ok but it also return true

What do I have to change in my code that the function will only return if the URL has a correctly, possible syntax and the file is a image?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a check for the TLD, followed by a forward slash :

```
url_validate = /(http(s?):)([\/|.|\w|\s|-])*\.[A-z]{2,}\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\.(?:jpg|gif|png)/;
```

The part that checks for the TLD is this : `\.[A-z]{2,}\/`
(match a period, match any letter between two and infinite times, match a forward slash)

Then i check the file name:

`[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\.`

Match any alphanumeric between one and infinite times, match a Period (.)

Then comes the file extension (like in your example)

If it is still unclear, check https://regex101.com/r/IGK58B/1

Comment: edit : after testing, i can confirm it works in the cases i feared it would not.